# How to realize arc carousel with swiperjs?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

guys! There is a problem happened when I try to realize a arc carousel like this(the following picture) with swiper.js. I do not know how to give a solution, the swiper version is 7.4.1. can you help me? very thanks!
more details:
the carousel is for a list of reward, every slide is a reward;
different number labeled by me on the picture, because they should have different zoom.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0nab.png)

what i try in a demo is like this,but I can not finish it to near the picture;

```
<template>
    <div id="carousel">
        <div class="swiper swiper-3d">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="img-placeholder">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="img-placeholder">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="img-placeholder">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="img-placeholder">4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="img-placeholder">5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import Swiper from 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';

export default {
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    mounted() {
        const slideW = 80; // 一张图300px, 每面四张角度22.5（PI/8），中心角度PI/16
        const radius = (slideW * 0.5) / Math.sin(Math.PI / 16); // 半径。圆心并不是视点中心，视点在1200px
        // const slideW = 80; // 将图片宽度设为200像素
        // const degree = Math.PI / 6; // 将每张图片的角度设为30度
        // const radius = (slideW * 0.5) / Math.sin(degree / 2); // 重新计算半径
        const carouselSwiper = new Swiper('#carousel .swiper', {
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            centeredSlides: false,
            centeredSlidesBounds: true,
            loop: true,
            // loopedSlides: 4,
            grabCursor: true,
            // autoplay: true,
            on: {
                progress(swiper, progress) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
                        const slide = this.slides.eq(i);
                        const slideProgress = this.slides[i].progress;
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-mixed-operators
                        const translateX = `${(slideProgress + 1.5) * (slideW / 3 - (Math.cos((slideProgress + 1.5) * 0.125 * Math.PI) * slideW * 1.1) / 3)}px`; // 调整图片间距，根据图片宽度改变数值实现自适应
                        const rotateY = (slideProgress + 1.5) * 22.5; // 图片角度
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-mixed-operators
                        const translateZ = `${radius - Math.cos((slideProgress + 1.5) * 0.125 * Math.PI) * radius - 150}px`; // 调整图片远近，刚好4个在画框内
                        const translateY = `${100}px`;
                        slide.transform(`translateX(${translateX}) translateZ(${0}) translateY(${translateY}) rotateY(${rotateY}deg)`);
                    }
                },
                setTransition(swiper, transition) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
                        const slide = this.slides.eq(i);
                        slide.transition(transition);
                    }
                },
            },
        });
    },
};
</script>

<style lang="less">
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    // padding-top: 50px;
    // padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.swiper-slide {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.img-placeholder {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #f00;
}
</style>
```